# iOS FCM notification not working in background

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm developing an app in Swift that have to use FCM as the notification service. In my app, the FCM works only when it's in foreground and not in the background.

I already tried several methods such as:

- disabling and enabling *swizzling* method
- set `priority` to `high`
- changed `data` to `notification` in my payload

I also got an error:

```
Failed to fetch APNS token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=1001 "(null)"
```

But the notification works in foreground without any problem. Below is my AppDelegate:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        FIRApp.configure()

        // Add observer for InstanceID token refresh callback.
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.tokenRefreshNotification),
                                                         name: kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification, object: nil)

        return true
    }

    func registerForPushNotifications(application: UIApplication) {
        let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(
            forTypes: [.Badge, .Sound, .Alert], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterUserNotificationSettings notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings) {
        if notificationSettings.types != .None {
            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
        let tokenChars = UnsafePointer<CChar>(deviceToken.bytes)
        var tokenString = ""

        for i in 0..<deviceToken.length {
            tokenString += String(format: "%02.2hhx", arguments: [tokenChars[i]])
        }

        //Tricky line
        FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.Unknown)
        print("Device Token:", tokenString)
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    // [START receive_message]
    func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Notification", message: "A standard alert", preferredStyle: .Alert)

        let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { (action:UIAlertAction!) in

        }
        alertController.addAction(OKAction)

        self.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion:nil)

        // Print message ID.
//        print("Message ID: \(userInfo["gcm.message_id"]!)")

        // Print full message.
        print("%@", userInfo)
    }
    // [END receive_message]

    // [START refresh_token]
    func tokenRefreshNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() {
            print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")
        }

        // Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempted before having a token.
        connectToFcm()
    }
    // [END refresh_token]

    // [START connect_to_fcm]
    func connectToFcm() {
        FIRMessaging.messaging().connectWithCompletion { (error) in
            if (error != nil) {
                print("Unable to connect with FCM. \(error)")
            } else {
                print("Connected to FCM.")
            }
        }
    }
    // [END connect_to_fcm]

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
        connectToFcm()
    }

    // [START disconnect_from_fcm]
    func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
        FIRMessaging.messaging().disconnect()
        print("Disconnected from FCM.")
    }
    // [END disconnect_from_fcm]
```

And in my server, I use something like this to push the notification:

```
method: 'POST',
            uri: 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization':'key= **THE KEY**'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                "to" : " **USER INSTANCEID TOKEN** ",
                "priority":"high",
                "data" : {
                    "title": "FCM TITLE",
                    "body" : "FROM FCM",
                    "badge": "0",
                    "sound": "default"
                }
            })
```

I tried searching everywhere, but can't find any solution and can't seem to find anything about this issue in the FCM documentation.

Comment: change your payload to have notification key instead of data, that will make it work in background too

Comment: @Shubhank I forgot to mention that I already change `data` to `notification` vice versa and nothing works for me

Comment: do you mean it does not work when app is in background or when app is in killed state ?

Comment: @Shubhank ya.. it does not work when in background

Comment: Have you tried including `content_available` with `true` value?

Comment: Also, are you sure that you've [uploaded the necessary certificates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#upload_your_apns_certificate)?

Comment: have u find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty new in the iOS\Swift... but i think maybe this code:

```
// [START disconnect_from_fcm]
    func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
        FIRMessaging.messaging().disconnect()
        print("Disconnected from FCM.")
    }
// [END disconnect_from_fcm]
```

logs you out of the firebase cloud messaging everytime the app goes to the background...and that is why you are not getting the notifications.

Can you try to comment out this method and see if it works?

LMK, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try add the `content_avaliable` with `true` value as @AL. said and add a `notification` object too. You can send a notification with both parameters (data and notification)

This works for me.

```
{
   "to" : " **USER INSTANCEID TOKEN** ",
   "priority":"high",
   "content_avaliable":true,
   "data" : {
        "title": "FCM TITLE",
        "body" : "FROM FCM",
        "badge": "0",
         "sound": "default"
   },
   "notification" : {
        "title": "FCM TITLE",
        "body" : "FROM FCM"
   }
}
```

UPDATE:
Is working only in my iPad, in iPhones the behavior continues.